# Renaming files in bash

Tags: bash

My directory has many files named as "20130101_temp.txt", "20130102_temp.txt", etc.

How do I remove the "_temp" in the names of all these files. i.e., rename 20130101_temp.txt to 20130101.txt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using bash:

```
for x in *_temp.txt
do
    mv $x ${x%%_temp.txt}.txt
done
```

There's also a utility that comes with Perl (at least on Ubuntu) called `rename` which takes a regular expression, so you could accomplish the same thing with:

```
rename -n 's/_temp\.txt$/.txt/' *_temp.txt
```

The `-n` option initiates a "dry run" that will only show you what is going to be renamed.  Remove it to actually perform the rename.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `for`-loop with a glob to find the files and a [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to remove the `_temp` for moving:

```
for t in ????????_temp.txt; do 
    echo mv ${t} ${t/_temp/}
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you've tested that the output looks right on your system.

Comment: comment on the echo is a nice touch, usually you learn that one the hard way

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for FILENAME in *_temp.txt; do
    mv $FILENAME `echo $FILENAME | sed -e 's/_temp//'`
done
```

It is usually a good idea to try it out first with the `mv` replaced with an `echo`.

Comment: Note: this solution depends on utilities outside of bash -- sed.  While most systems may have that utility, not all will.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bash solution but since I encounter renaming tasks frequently while being way to lazy to think about a reasonable bash solution, I just got pyRenamer, a GUI tool that does things like that quite well. It's usually installable from the standard repositories.

dlundquists solution works quite well though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
find . -depth -name '*_temp*' -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv -i "$f" "${f//_temp/ }"; done' bash {} +
```