# Batch rename files

Tags: linux, bash, rename, file-rename

I want to batch re-name a number of files in a directory so that the preceding number and hypen are stripped from the file name.

```
Old file name: 2904495-XXX_01_xxxx_20130730235001_00000000.NEW
New file name:         XXX_01_xxxx_20130730235001_00000000.NEW
```

How can I do this with a linux command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming files in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370416/renaming-files-in-bash)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should make it:

```
rename 's/^[0-9]*-//;' *
```

It gets from the beginning the block `[0-9]` (that is, numbers) many times, then the hyphen `-` and deletes it from the file name.

---

If `rename` is not in your machine, you can use a loop and `mv`:

```
mv "$f" "${f#[0-9]*-}"
```

#### Test

```
$ ls
23-aa  hello aaa23-aa
$ rename 's/^[0-9]*-//;' *
$ ls
aa  hello aaa23-aa
```

Or:

```
$ ls
23-a  aa23-a  hello
$ for f in *;
> do
>   mv "$f" "${f#[0-9]*-}"
> done
$ ls
a  aa23-a  hello
```

Comment: This doesn't work with my version of `rename` (util-linux-ng 2.17.2). What version are you using?

Comment: rename is in util-linux on Fedora and Debian releases, but doesn't seem to be included by default on OSX.

Comment: @Yossarian check my updated answer, using `mv`. Does it work to you?

Comment: Yep, the `mv` command works for me. It seems there must be two versions of `rename` - mine requires three arguments (`rename from to file`).

Comment: @cjungel not sure what you mean

Answer (score 22):

I think this command would better if you execute the command below:

```
ls * | sed -e 'p;s/old-name/new-name/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

Here 
**ls ***    - lists  files  in curent folder
**sed -e**  - executes  expression
**p;**      - prints old file name 
**s/old-name/new-name/**  - produce new filename 
**xargs -n2**  - handles  two arguments  to mv
**mv**         - gets two parameters  and  do move  operation

**Recommendation:**   before  executing  mv  verify  what you do is what you want to achieve  with **echo**.

```
ls * | sed -e 'p;s/old-name/new-name/' | xargs -n2 echo
```

Following  example renames

SCCF099_FG.gz5329223404623884757.tmp  **to**
SCCF099_FG.gz

```
ls *tmp | sed -e 'p;s/\([0-9]\)\+\.tmp/ /g' | xargs -n2 echo
ls *tmp | sed -e 'p;s/\([0-9]\)\+\.tmp/ /g' | xargs -n2 mv
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I see this is old; but can you break down what's going on in this line? Here's my understanding: in the call to `sed`, if say there are 5 files present, the expression string prints each line and then prints its find-and-replaced copy immediately below; then, `xargs` parses this list of *10 items* now 2-at-a-time, and passes them as arguments to `mv`. Is that right?

Comment: Slight variation I used for filenames containing spaces: `find . -print0 | sed -z -e 'p;s/old-name/new-name/' | xargs -n2 -0 mv`.

Answer (score 7):

If the first numbers are always the same length:

```
for F in *new ; do
    mv $F ${F:8}
done
```

The `${parameter:number}` does a substring expansion - takes the string starting at the 8th character.

There are many other string edits available in expansions to handle other cases.

Answer (score 3):

Using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer) (Windows, Mac and Linux friendly):

```
$ renamer --find '/\d+-(.*)/' --replace '$1' *
```

This will strip all numbers and first hyphen from the start of all files in the current directory.

Comment: Is it possible to install with dependencies ?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean.. there are install instructions on the [renamer site](https://github.com/75lb/renamer).. does that help?

Comment: node package manager seems having issues with package dependencies, so it didn't install just one command, and npm didn't install dependencies in auto mode.

Comment: i just ran `npm install -g renamer` - it installed correctly and works fine.. please ensure you have the latest node.js installed.. if you're still having problems, raise an issue [here](https://github.com/75lb/renamer)

Answer (score 2):

This might look a little complex, but it's pretty effective and works well on both *nix and OSX systems. It also acts recursively, renaming files in the current directory as well as any subdirectories:

```
find . -regex '.*/[0-9]\{7\}[-].*' -print > temp1 && \
cp temp1 temp2 && \
vi -c ":g/\([0-9]\{7\}[-]\)\(.*\)/s//\2/" -c ":x" temp2 && \
paste temp1 temp2 > temp3 && \
vi -c ":g/^/s//mv /" -c ":x" temp3 && \
sh ./temp3 && \
rm temp1 temp2 temp3
```

Here's a breakdown of what just happened:

The first line says to find (`find`) all files, starting with those in the current directory (`.`), whose name matches the pattern (`-regex`) of "7 numbers, followed by a dash, followed by 0 or more characters" (`'.*/[0-9]\{7\}[-].*'`), and write those file names and their respective paths (`-print`) to a file called *temp1* (`> temp1`). Note that the `-print` directive is probably not necessary in most cases but it shouldn't hurt anything.

```
find . -regex '.*/[0-9]\{7\}[-].*' -print > temp1 && \
```

Then, copy (`cp`) the contents of *temp1* to a file called *temp2*.

```
cp temp1 temp2 && \
```

Next, open the file *temp2* using the [**vi** text editor](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html) and give vi two commands (using `-c` to signify each new command):

1. Command #1:

   - Search each line of *temp2* (`:g`) for the same pattern we searched for above, except this time group the results using parentheses (`\([0-9]\{7\}[-]\)\(.*\)`).
   - For each matching line, move the cursor to where the match was found and replace the whole match with only the second group of the matched pattern (`\2`).
2. Command #2:

   - Save the changes made to *temp2* and close the file (`:x`).

The result of which being this:

```
 vi -c ":g/\([0-9]\{7\}[-]\)\(.*\)/s//\2/" -c ":x" temp2 && \
```

Now, concatenate the lines from *temp1* with those of *temp2* (`paste`) and write each newly combined line to a file called *temp3* (`> temp3`).

```
paste temp1 temp2 > temp3 && \
```

Next, run **vi** again, doing the same steps as above except this time search for the beginning of each line (`^`) inside the file *temp3* and add [**mv**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) and one space right after it (`mv`).

```
vi -c ":g/^/s//mv /" -c ":x" temp3 && \
```

Then, execute the contents of *temp3* (`./temp3`) as a shell script (`sh`).

```
sh ./temp3 && \
```

Finally, remove (`rm`) each of the temporary files we created during the whole process.

```
rm temp1 temp2 temp3
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a handy GUI tool `pyRenamer`
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/pyRenamer/

Answer (score 1):

[vimv](https://github.com/thameera/vimv) lets you rename multiple files using Vim's text editing capabilities.

Entering vimv opens a Vim window which lists down all files and you can do pattern matching, visual select, etc to edit the names. After you exit Vim, the files will be renamed.

The [screencast](https://github.com/thameera/vimv/blob/master/screencast.gif) in the README file shows how it solves original poster's question.

[Disclaimer: I'm the author of the tool]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool: [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm)

Code to do what you want:

```
rnm /path/to/the/directory -fo -dp -1 -rs '/^\d+-//' -ss '^\d+-'
```

`-fo` is for file only mode
`-dp` is the depth of directory ( `-1` means unlimited depth).
`-rs` is replace string. `\d+-` regex is being replaced with empty string.
`-ss` is search string, it searches for files with `^\d+-` regex. (It could be omitted though, some harmless error messages would be printed on screen).

Answer (score 0):

I really like something as "rename *.mp3 *.mp4".

But none of other answers give me that. So I wrote a haskell program to do it.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/batch-rename

With this you can do:
 batch_rename "DCIM*.jpg" "*.png"