# How to batch rename a file of specific file type within subdir?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to batch rename all files within a specific subdirectory. Why does the following give a syntax error?

```
RENAME .\webapps\*.war .\webapps\Test.war
```

Comment: Please can you **edit your question** to include the syntax error you receive?

Comment: Also this would give all file the same name?! Does that make any sense?

Comment: The syntax is `whatToRename howToRename`, so in the how there should be not path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `rename` with a target name that includes a path.

```
RENAME .\webapps\*.war Test.war
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in your statement: Do you want to change all the files to the same name? It's impossible.

And you might use `rename` the wrong way, please refer to `man rename`.

```
NAME
   rename - renames multiple files

SYNOPSIS
   rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]

DESCRIPTION
   "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the first argument.    The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is
   expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some of the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the expression, it will not
   be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the command line, filenames will be read via standard input.

   For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the extension, you might say

           rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak

   To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use

           rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *

OPTIONS
   -v, --verbose
           Verbose: print names of files successfully renamed.

   -n, --no-act
           No Action: show what files would have been renamed.

   -f, --force
           Force: overwrite existing files.
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743284/batch-rename-files) might also be useful.